# Can a foreign eyeglass prescription be used to buy glasses or contacts in the US?

Tags: health

Is it possible to get an eye exam done in a foreign country and come back to the US with prescriptions for glasses and contacts and have that filled by ideally one of the online retailers?

Comment: When I did it, I just plugged in the numbers. There was literally no way for anyone to know where I got them from.

Comment: FWIW, the U.S. is an expensive place to get eyeglasses made. I know a great many people who get them in Latin America or Asia instead.

Comment: If you have rather standard eyes with rather standard corrections needed, you might well do it online. But if you have non-standard corrections needed I would not do anything but going to a shop which is willing to check the prescription to your eyes and actually fit the glasses to your head.

Comment: Yes It works on most sites but not all. Warby Parker won’t take my money because my prescription doesn’t have an expiry date. Eyeglasses USA took my prescription without any issue.

Answer (score 6):

Knowledge from the comments on the question, no personal experience here.

You can use a foreign prescription for glasses on several of the online USA glasses sites, but not on all.
And some will have restrictions on which prescriptions are acceptable, like an expiry date.

But warning, if your glasses or lenses need to be 'non standard' because your eyes have 'non standard' problems, you best go to a place where they check the prescription to your eyes and measure and adjust the glasses to your head or check the shape of your eyes for your lenses.
A slight offset of the glass in the glasses will make them hard to use, or even worse.